# Powershell save functions

Tags: function, powershell, save

I already know how to make a function in powershell. The problem is: How do I save that function so I can use it in the future?

When I write myFunction{3+3} in Powershell I can use that function in that session.

Altough, if I quit powershell and open it again, that function is gone. How do I "save" the function so I can use it even after I restart Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in your Powershell profile:

Rather than explain it here, try this article:

http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways:

You can compose it to a module and load it with `import-module functions.psm1` into a script or via use the ps profile.

You can also dot sourc any saved functions into another ps1 ( `. .\functions.ps1`).